# creating a numpy vector using 3 components

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a vector in numpy using 3 components Vx, Vy, Vz as sown below. Can anyone help? Thank you

```
from numpy import cos, sin

Vx = cos(alpha)* cos(beta)
Vy = sin(alpha)*cos(beta)
Vz = sin(beta)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With NumPy, vectors (and matrices for that matter) are just Python arrays.  As in

```
from numpy import array
myVector = array([Vx, Vy, Vz])
myMatrix = array([[Vx, Vy, Vz], [1,2,3]])
```